# RESTful Java Client with POST method

Tags: java, rest

i have problem with my Rest Client. 
**My Service**

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public Response getNumber(String a){
    return Response.status(201).entity("Number is: "+a.toString()).build();
}
```

**My Client**

```
   try{
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RESTform/core/take/post");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        String input = "123";
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));
        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e){}
    catch(IOException e){}
```

My path is: ProjectName/core/take/post
After Debug on a Server in Eclipse i get a message:

type Status report,
message Method Not Allowed,
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
Tomcat 8.0.9

Please help me :(

Comment: Your path annotation at class level please.

Comment: @Path("/take")
Path is good in my opinion

Comment: What is `core` in the requested path `/RESTform/core/take/post` then ?

Comment: Its a namespace from web.xml :)

Comment: When i change POST to GET i have on my page "Number is:" without 123... i dont understand this

Comment: Did you try using a different client, like Postman or curl? I suspect the problem is on the client side...

Comment: No i don't, and no one in tutorials use this so how it is working to them?

Comment: The same block of code submitted by you works fine for me. I get the following response : `Output from Server .... 

Number is: 123
`

Comment: How it is possible? Which .jars you add? 
I have in my project jersey-core,server,client 1.9.
I even dont have Output from server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included only the jars(all) provided by `jersey 1.9` version into my library.

Here is the REST Service :

`import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
@Path("/hello")`

```
public class HelloWorld {

@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes("text/plain")
public Response getNumber(String a){
    return Response.status(201).entity("Number is: "+a.toString()).build();
}
}
```

And here is the rest client : `import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;`

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:5050/REST-simple/rest-simple/hello/post");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        String input = "123";
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));
        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}}
```

Try this you should get the output.

Comment: With POST method i have "Method not Allowed" 405, and with GET method i still dont have 123...

Comment: You should be getting the correct result, because i have achieved it. If not then specify more details about your environment and how you are trying it out.

Comment: I have proxy on my computer on web, i am using Eclipse Luna newest version with java 7 update 67 jersey 1.9. What can i tell you more? :)